# How to create elastic search using mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement elastic search with mongodb as my database using node.js for development.Im unable to figure out what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two possible interpretations for your question and I'm not sure which one is right, so I'll address both.

1. You want to synchronize a MongoDB database with ElasticSearch. For this, check out [river-mongodb](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb).
2. You want ElasticSearch-like text searching capabilities in MongoDB. For this, MongoDB has [text indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/).